# AWS EC2 instance with custom AMI rarely doesn't launch upon creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

We are using AWS EC2 via cloud formation to launch stacks of instances.  We create stacks that are combinations of custom and marketplace images.  This worked perfectly until Friday.  Starting on Friday, 10/7, about 10% of all instances we launch simply stall upon launch. So far we have only seen this for the custom AMIs we created (both Win7 and Win10) but I'm not sure if that is a coincidence or not as the stack is mostly comprised of instance launching from those 2 AMIs.

Note that we did not change the AMIs recently nor have we changed anything else about our process.

The issue eventually manifests as a failure when cloud formation times out.

I detached one of the boot volumes and attached it to a working instance so that I could view the logs.  There are simply no new entries from the attempted launch in the following logs (or any accompanied error logs)

- Ec2ConfigLog.txt
- %WINDIR%\Panther\SetupAct.log
- %WINDIR%\Panther\UnattendGC\SetupAct.log

The screenshot of the instance (via the AWS console) shows a static windows icon with no text around it.

Grabbing the system log (via the AWS console) returns nothing (empty console).

Force stopping and then starting the instance does kick off the customization and launch of windows but building in a restart upon failure is a hack I really don't want to do, even if cloud formation allows it (about which I'm not sure).

Does anyone have ideas for how we can troubleshoot further?

Thanks!
Jason

Comment: How long is your timeout, and how long did you leave the instance to "do it's thing" ? Perhaps your timeout just isn't long enough.

Comment: Thanks Matt!  The timeout is 4 hours.  The machine usually completes this step in 17-20 minutes so unfortunately I don't think that is it.

Comment: did u try launching EC2 Instance with the Custom AMIs without cloudformation(Manually)? Try that and check if it is working...

Comment: Thanks Ali!  I have done that and haven't been able to reproduce the issue, though I may not have tried enough times.  Note that the issue described above is extremely inconsistent/rare.